# Rails how to ignore RecordNotUnique, when processing a bulk insert?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, exception

I'm processing some xml data where there can happen to be some records which already got entered into the db. I solved that problem with a index on two columns, but know it happens to not entering any value (not even the unique ones) and just raise RecordNotUnique Exception. How can a tell the process that it should just not enter this record, but should go on, entering the next records of the xml file?

Thanks for any help!
Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap your code in:

```
begin
...
rescue RecordNotUnique => exception
 next
end
```

seems to be you have a loop for XML parsing. So it will skip 'bad' record and continue operation.

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately... when I debug this, the exeption never gets called... But the console tell's me that this RecordNotUnique is really the case!

Comment: I just had to restart the server, cause i do the calculation in a separat file which is stored in the lib directory...